# Creating a Protobuf file from CSV

Tags: python, csv, protocol-buffers

Good day everyone. I need to create a simple file in Protobuf (proto) format, preferably using Python (I'm currently using PyCharm). It should be very simple and resemble the following CSV structure:

header = ['Surname', 'Name']
data = ['John', 'Doe']

If anyone knows how to do it, it would help me a lot. Thanks!

I have already transformed this CSV structure into a Parquet file and tried doing the same for Protobuf, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What issues have you faced?

```
syntax="proto3";

message Data {
  string surname = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

message CSV {
  repeated Data data = 1;
}
```

or

```
syntax="proto3";

message Data {
  string data1 = 1;
  string data2 = 2;
}

message CSV {
  string header1 = 1;
  string header2 = 2;
  repeated Data data = 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never worked with something like this before, so I was confused and didn't understand the principles of how Protobuf works. I think I'm on a right way now. I plan on using the file structure you created in Python, will try to write data entries to it.